# Regular expression, specific last character type in a capture group

Tags: java, regex

The regex I currently have is:

```
"^(?:(\\.\\.)|^([a-z]+[a-z.\\-]*)([\\*]?)[\\[]*([^\\]]*)[\\]]*)$";
```

It captures either ".." (group 1) with group 2-4 being empty
**or**:
 - a group of lowercase, dots, dashes. starting with lowercase (group 2)
 - followed by optional asterisk (group 3)
 - followed by optional content within square brackets (group 4)

I'm having a couple problems, first is making it so group2 must end with a letter, I have tried many things including:

```
"^([a-z]+[a-z.\\-]*[a-z]$)"
"^([a-z]+[a-z.\\-]*[a-z])$"
```

which kills anything in group 3-4

```
"^([a-z]+[a-z.\\-]*[a-z])"
```

which doesn't seem to do anything different

---

The other problem I'm having is group 4, it doesn't depend on the square brackets (which makes sense as I have the * character for them)... but if I remove that character it will not give me any results for ANY of the groups.

Any help is greatly needed and appreciated.

---

In response to comment below, the following should match:
`"string" - (group1)(group2)(group3)(group4)`

```
".." - (..)()()()
"blah" - ()(blah)()()
"blah.blah" - ()(blah.blah)()()
"blah.blah*" - ()(blah.blah)(*)()
"blah*" - ()(blah)(*)()
"blah.blah*[foobar] - ()(blah.blah)(*)(foobar)
"blah[foobar] - ()(blah)()(foobar)
```

The following should not match:

```
 "."
 "..."
 ".blah"
 "blah."
 ".blah*"
 "blah.*[foobar]
```

Comment: can you provide some sample input that you expect to match/not match?

Comment: Can you provide some sample strings that you would like to match and capture?

Comment: Lol @davidrac: we asked the same question around the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
                   ┌ one or more lowercase letters followed by
                   │ 
                   │   ┌ none or several occurrences of ───────────────────────┐
                   │   │     ┌ dot or dash                                     │
                   │   │     │     ┌ followed by one or more lowercase letters │
                   │   │     │     │     ┌─────────────────────────────────────┘
                   │   │     │     │     │ 
                   │   │     │     │     │  ┌ followed by optional asterisk
                   │   │     │     │     │  │
                   │   │     │     │     │  │   ┌ followed by optional square brackets
            ┌ or   │   │     │     │     │  │   │         ┌ with some content inside │
            │      │   │     │     │     │  │   │         │        ┌─────────────────┘
            │      │   │     │     │     │  │   │         │        │
^(?:(\\.\\.)|(?:([a-z]+(?:[.\\-]*[a-z]+)*)(\\*?)(?:\\[([^\\]]*)\\])?))$
│   │      │                                                          │
│   └ two  │                                                          │
│     dots ┘                                                          │
│                                                                     │
└ start of string                                       end of string ┘
```

Comment: needed the grouping, your second example was a plug and play - passed all my test cases, thanks

Comment: if you dont mind explaining, how is this able to pass "blah.foo.bar", it is actually what i want, but i'm not sure how it is doing it... from looking at it i read it as: "start with 1 or more letter, contain 0 or more dots or dashes, end with 1 or more letter", i dont see how it can allow letters between dots/dashes

Answer (score 0):

This is what I could come up with:

```
^(\.{2})?([a-z](?:\.*-*[a-z])*)?(\*)?(\[[^]]*\])?$
```

I'm not sure what's allowed in the brackets, so it matches any non bracket letter in there.

(properly escaped:   `^(\\.{2})?([a-z](?:\\.*-*[a-z])*)?(\\*)?(\\[[^]]*\\])?$`  )

This regex: `[a-z](?:\.*-*[a-z])*` will always match a string that starts and ends with a lowercase letter.

Comment: this one fails the following test cases: "..blah", ""

it should not work with empty string and should not start with dots. the only case starting with dots that should pass is ".." (nothing else except 2 dots).

I modified it to this:    "^(?:(\\.{2})|^([a-z](?:\\.*-*[a-z])*)(\\*)?(\\[[^]]*\\])?)$"

and it is passing all of my test cases. Thanks